# How to filter nodes with specifc attribute and preserve the path using networkx graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

These days I am working on networkx graph. 
Let us say I have this graph. Priority 1 with the blue nodes, priority 2 with the yellow nodes, priority 3 with purple nodes, and priority 4 with green nodes.

[image]

I would like to filter by priority level. For example the first priority 1, it should filter nodes with blule color. I would like to keep nodes with blue color (priority 1) and  ignore the rest, And it should look like this.

[image]

And for priority 2, including nodes for priority, it should show nodes with the yellow color. Keeping priority 1 (with blue color) and priority 2 (yellow color). Here I should keep the path from 10 to 190 since there is a path from the ignored nodes. And it should look like this.

[image]

And the same for priority 3 and 4. For example for priority 3, I would like to keep priority 1, 2, and 3 together as I showed at priority level 2.

This how I started.

```
collector = nx.DiGraph()
for n1, atrr1 in g1.nodes(data ='True'):
    for n2, atrr2 in g1.nodes(data ='True'):
        if ((g1.node[n1]['priority'] ==1) & (g1.node[n2]['priority'] ==2)):

            if (has_path(g1,n1, n2)):
                collector.add_edge(n1,n2)

        if ((g1.node[n2]['priority'] ==2) & (g1.node[n1]['priority'] ==2)):

            if (has_path(g1,n1, n2)):
                collector.add_edge(n1,n2) 


nx.draw(collector, with_labels = True, pos = nx.spring_layout(collector))
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [6,6]
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Can anyone help me to do this in python?

Comment: Any lead in this? I am working on this same thing.

Comment: @PoojaSonkar What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to compute the graph reachability matrix (square matrix that has a `1` in row `a`, column `b` if node `b` is reachable from node `a` via the graphs edges). You can find how to implement this [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability).
Then, all you have to do is filter out the nodes you want and re-draw the edges just for the filtered nodes using the computed matrix (by going over only the rows and columns corresponding to nodes that appear in the new graph and drawing an edge where there is a `1`).

Comment: Thank you, alon-k. That is really helpful hint. I tried with one of the algorithm for reachability which is dfs. But not succeed. 

`for n1, n2 in g1.nodes(data = True):
    if ((g1.node[n1]['priority']==1) ):
        edges = nx.dfs_successors(g1, n1)
        nodes = []
        for k,v in edges.items():
            nodes.extend([k])
            nodes.extend(v)
        H = g1.subgraph(nodes)
        nx.draw(H, with_labels = True, pos = nx.circular_layout(H))`

Comment: Could you edit your post with that code so it will be more readable? I will try to see why it didn't work